# What's the largest practical stable gain possible?

Tags: analog, feedback, gain, loop-gain, gain-bandwidth-product

I have a feedback application to set the voltage of a node in which there is considerable loss in the loop. Simulations tell me that a differential voltage gain of 10000, 80dB (roughly about what you normally get from a single open-loop opamp) is not adequate and I would need on the order of 140dB to make the application feasible.

Note that noise is not really an issue in this application (within reason), but a bandwidth of ~1MHz is desirable, which sets a somewhat insane GBW product of \$~10^{13}\$. In addition I need very low input bias current (<1µA.)

A multi-stage amplifier does not seem viable, as this would increase the order of the system and would tend to make it unstable under feedback conditions. Before I even start considering discrete designs and optimizations (or building my own ICs for this application), or simply scratch the whole idea and go back to the drawing board, I would like to know how viable this would be:

1. What is the largest single-stage/single-pole wide-bandwidth gain/GBW attainable (I seem to recall that a gain of ~200 is about the limit of discrete electronics).
2. What is the largest dual-stage gain/GBW attainable (most op amps would fall into this category).
3. Could a multi-stage (>3) amplifier be compensated in such a way to make this possible?
4. What is the largest gain/GBW op amp currently available in the market?
5. Would a different topology (e.g., Norton or Transconductance amplifier) provide a way around these limitations?

I am currently designing around a somewhat hard to get LTC6269IDD-10. A non-unity gain compensated 4GHz GBW op amp. But even this is proving to be a challenge.

**Conceptual schematic**
(note that most parameters cannot be modified and are somewhat random in nature, that includes the resistors, capacitors, and signal source):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ShDa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Related questions:

[What's special about "unity-gain stable"?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39048/whats-special-about-unity-gain-stable)

[What is the largest gain configurable with an opamp?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256149/what-is-the-largest-gain-configurable-with-an-opamp)

Comment: I think a current feedback amp is what you need here, but I don't have enough experience to say much more than that.

Comment: Maybe you need to **compensate** for the loss in the feedback not by increasing the gain in the overall loop but by adding an amplifier (before or after that attenuation) with its own feedback. That way the requirement on the gain in the overall loop becomes much lower.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Given the requirement of ~80dB, that is already an op-amp in open loop (with all of its poles). But it does add a few possibilities, in case I can reduce the gain requirements by a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: *Given the requirement of ~80dB, that is already an op-amp in open loop* Then divide that over two or more cascaded amplifiers, each an opamp with their own feedback. ~80 dB in one loop sounds to me like too much for one loop especially if you need a BW that is more than a few kHz.

Comment: You're going to get more than -80dB coupling in the power supply rails and other parasitic sources.  Basically, your feedback signal will get swamped by your own amplifier output.  It may be a good idea to post a schematic, if you can.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie _80 dB in one loop sounds to me like too much for one loop_ I agree. That's why I am asking this question. But note that the purpose of the gain is to create that loop to force a voltage in a particular node, I am not just amplifying a signal to be used elsewhere, so a cascade of amplifiers would not work for this application (without some serious compensation, that is)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that will almost guarantee oscillation in this application unless some state-space compensation method is developed which would require discrete electronics, as op-amps might not be observable enough for that. (Note: we are talking of (140/3)dB ~50dB per stage which is still excessive). The objective is the feedback loop, not the signal.

Comment: Can yout explain a bit more about what you are trying to do? I see a bit of a disconnect between your comment about noise not being an issue and a gain of 140dB. If your output signal is in the 1V range then you're looking at 100nV input signal. If that has a bandwidth of 1MHz  that's white noise in the 100pV/rt(Hz) range which is ummm.. challenging.

Comment: @TimWescott I added a conceptual schematic (it would work perfectly if I could find one of those "Ideal op-amps" I keep hearing about....)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am trying to remove interference from a node. The reason that noise is not an issue is that this would be common-mode to my actual measurement which could tolerate ~10mV of RMS random noise or a very lax 10µV/sqrt(Hz).

Comment: The model looks wrong to me to remove CM noise. It should not be a local ground compared to a remote signal with GBW=1e14 and a 90 deg LPF to reduce phase margin, rather a differential amp with a shield driven by the DM signal to shunt CM noise with unity gain. Aka Active guarding uses in EEG. With 1MHz CM choke.

Comment: What output voltage at 1MHz, will you need?

Comment: I recall measuring the Rout of a 3-transistor current mirror, on a Fairchild Curve Tracer, as about 5MegOhm. A bipolar diffpair running at 20mA would have transconductance of 1/2.6 ohms; Combine the mirror and the diffpair, and you have Av of 2,000,000X.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Re: _What output voltage at 1MHz_ that's a bit up in the air as I am dealing with imperfect models and parasitics. What I DO know is that I need to be able to attenuate ~1Vpp @ 100kHz at the target node, which implies on the order of 10Vpp on the feedback circuitry (this is not desirable for different reasons, so I am addressing this separately, and would rather stay below 5Vpp in general).

Comment: Not sure if you will be able to find one that meets your bandwidth requirements, but some instrumentation amplifiers are capable of attaining gains of 10,000+.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the largest single-stage/single-pole wide-bandwidth gain/GBW
>   attainable (I seem to recall that a gain of ~200 is about the limit of
>   discrete electronics).

[These chopping amplifiers](http://www.emelectronics.co.uk/a29.html) are the highest gains I've seen, at 240dB or higher with a unity gain of 300kHz. Thats a GBWP of 3*10^29, Don't get too excited, they are expensive.

> What is the largest dual-stage gain/GBW attainable (most op amps would
>   fall into this category). Could a multi-stage (>3) amplifier be compensated in such a 
>   way to make this possible?

IMO the main problem will be noise, especially if the op amps have a high gain feedback network. The problem is the noise of the first will be multiplied by the second, so if you have a gain of 10^6 on the second stage and a 1uVpp noise on the first stage, the second stage will see 1Vpp of noise from the first. 1uVpp isn't going to be useful for most designs.

In all of the high gain systems I've designed, it's best to take care of most of the gain in the first stage. Even resistors become major noise sources at 1MΩ, and if you want a gain of "only" 10^6. 1/F noise is an even larger problem with high gain.

But really, what are you trying to do? Typical analog digital systems have a pre amp that feeds into an ADC. If the noise is gained up, one will only be increasing the number of noisy bits on an ADC. Even if the preamp is not being used for digital conversion, noise still applies in control systems. In my experience it's really SNR that matters, so if that figure hasn't been calculated then it should be.

There are multi stage options, on the preamp stage, the [amplifiers can be paralleled](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/paralleling-amplifiers-improves-signal-to-noise-performance.html) for lower noise, with the noise being \$\sqrt(2)N_{amps}\$. Typically with normal op-amps gains higher than 10000 are difficult. I have tried paralleling op amps for lower noise, it works well.

> Would a different topology (e.g., Norton or Transconductance
>   amplifier) provide a way around these limitations?

Not that I know of, the way to get around high gain problems is most likely chopping amplifiers which help lower noise. The learning curve is very steep however.

Another way to get around these problems is to divide up the bandwidth into different signal chains. For example: you need 1e13 with a bandwidth of 1e6, which means a gain of 1e7 at DC. One way to divide this up would be to have a multi stage signal chain with bandpass filters. One chain could cover 100Hz with a gain of 1e7 then another stage could cover 100Hz to 1000Hz with a gain of 1e7, the next would cover 1kHz to 1000kHz ect. This is only an illustration.

Whatever you do, it is going to be both costly in both hardware and time to design. Now would be a good time to look at the system level requirements and make sure that they are correct and the cost of this design is justified.

The largest practical stable closed loop gains possible (V/V) that are useful would IMO be around 10000.

Comment: Yikes! I would like to see the design of that chopper.

Comment: How the absolute (censored) does that chopper amplifier work‽

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single-stage-of-gain opamp, gain about 100,000; was gain-of-ten stable, settling in about 7 nanoSeconds for 1nanoSecond input edge, gain of 11X.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIY0fL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Not seeing how this helps in any way.

Comment: The OP wonders if 200x is the largest possible gain in a stage. This says no.

Comment: How is this better than any modern op amp with a open loop gain of more than 10e6 (which is quite common)? What is the noise on this amp?

Comment: Notice the settling time.

Comment: @laptop2d could you point out to those op amps? I am not sure I have seen anything above \$ 10^{5} \$ of open loop gain.

Comment: Here is a list of op amps with 120db+ open loop gain https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11070#/p4115=120|280&d=sel|4501|4500|4502|300|4115|2687|4101|s3|s5|4108|2839|2840 (if it works right)

Comment: @laptop2d thanks!! I guess I never bothered to look at that column. But, as normal, the compromises I'll have to make might be unacceptable for other reasons (just GBW reduced my choices to two), all the ones I looked at would require quite a bit of redesign.